# How to fix app crash when requesting permission in react native with react-native-gps-state library?

Tags: react-native

My app crashes when requesting GPS permission through the `react-native-gps-state` npm library.

Here is the crash log,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback.invoke(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference

com.facebook.react.modules.permissions.PermissionsModule.onRequestPermissionsResult PermissionsModule.java:205
com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate$1.invoke ReactActivityDelegate.java:178
com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onResume ReactActivityDelegate.java:108
com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onResume ReactActivity.java:66
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume Instrumentation.java:1337
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: did you solved this issue if yes please help me I am having same issue.